# vb.net periodically fetch datas from database

Tags: database, vb.net, periodic-task

I've some trouble to periodically get datas from my database.
I've got a list of clients connected to my server. I need to retrieve selected datas from my database using a query.

My function returns a MySqlDataAdapter and have string as parameter.
I use my function in my client's threads. Here is my function :

```
Function TachesEnvoi(ByVal idClient As String) As MySqlDataAdapter
        MyTachesEnvoi.Connectionstring = RequeteConnBDD
        MyTachesEnvoi.Open()

            Dim StrTachesEnvoi As String = "select * from alertes 
            where id_alerte IN (select Alertes_id_Alerte FROM bddalertes.alertehisto 
            WHERE id_histo IN (select alertehisto_id_histo from tachesenvoi where traite = 0 and Utilisateur_id_Utilisateur ='" & idClient & "'));"

            Dim CmdTachesEnvoi As New MySqlCommand(StrTachesEnvoi, MyTachesEnvoi)
            Dim AdaptateurTachesEnvoi As New MySqlDataAdapter(CmdTachesEnvoi)
            CmdTachesEnvoi.Dispose()
            MyTachesEnvoi.Close()
            Console.WriteLine("fin de tachesenvoi")

            Return AdaptateurTachesEnvoi

    End Function
```

I tried to check a solution with timer but i didn't manage to do it..

I have no idea of how to do this, if anyone have en idea i'll be very happy, and thanksful ! x)

(sorry for my english, french guy)

Comment: What did you try with the `Timer`?  How did it not work as expected?  It sounds like you want to perform a periodic background task on a separate thread, and a `Timer` seems suited to that job.  Also, be aware that your code has a SQL injection vulnerability.  You should probably look into using query parameters instead of directly executing input as code.

Comment: Make sure that you tried with [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), and not System.Windows.Forms.Timer!

Comment: Thanks guys ! 
I manage to do it otherwise. I have to "ping" my clients inside their threads. Each time i get a response from the client I check the datas from the database, and if i get something, I send it to the client.
Not pretty but it works !